# LAN-side UDP Flood

Tags: ddos

My internet has been really slow these days, and it takes around 5 minutes after the computer starts to even being able to open a webpage.
I've checked my router logs and it says I'm being port scanned by some random IP and apparently my PC is causing an UDP Flood.

I've tried googling this and some of the causes for this was having a video service(youtube) open, I let my computer on for a few minutes without opening anything, and the internet was still slow and my logs still showed port scans and LAN side UDP floods, my main questions are:

Am I infected by some kind of malware?

and/or

Am I being DDoS'd?

I've ran my anti-virus(Eset Nod32) several times searching for malware but it always came up clean. My router is from netgear(not sure if this is relevant info)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXAtX.jpg logs

Comment: The packet count does not look like a DOS attack of any relevance. I would rather suspect the problem inside your computer, i.e. misconfiguration, bad behaving software or browser extensions or even a hardware problem.

Comment: Don't (only) put images of logs in your text, they are not searchable.

Comment: Port scans are normal, and it doesn't look like a high frequency. The UDP traffic from inside your network is interesting. You will need to look at the logs from 192.168.0.18 to see what's going on. Can't tell from just the router. Though, there is only the one instance in the 5 minute window you show, so that's not likely to be flooding your connection.

Comment: It was the wrong image I'm sorry, but I' m also getting SYN Flood attempts now as you can see on the image
http://imgur.com/9xht7hj
.

Comment: Also, do you have any advice on how to check if it's the software's or hardware's fault?

Comment: I've brought my computer to another network, as far as I can tell it's not the computers fault, everything is super fast and working normally.